# Drop and insert data using Custom SQL in Tableau Desktop

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create temporary tables and insert data into Snowflake using custom sql on Tableau Desktop. I'm receiving the following error message:

```
SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 13 unexpected '#t'."
```

The query that I'm trying to use is:

```sql
create table #temp1
select distinct ....
```

Comment: You need to use a stored procedure.  Tableau Desktop custom sql doesn't support temp tables.  You should be aware of [this](https://tableaulove.tumblr.com/post/73233020180/calling-a-temp-table-inside-a-stored-procedure#_=_) regarding temp tables in stored procedures used in Tableau

Answer (score 0):

To create a temporary table, you need to use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE command. The temp table names do not start with # in Snowflake as in Microsoft SQL Server:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-temp-transient.html#creating-a-temporary-table

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#optional-parameters